# Run Age of Empires II in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wine, winetricks

I'm quite new using Ubuntu. I already installed Age of Empires II The Forgotten Empires using wine. The thing is that I cann't run it through the direct access created on desktop. I installed PlayOnLinux too, but I don't know how to run the game. Can anybody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good news, I  haven't tested everything yet but i've managed to get this working in PlayOnlinux and start a game in 17.10.1:

1. Open PLayOnLinux and select 'Install a Program'.

[image: POL Install a program]

---

2. Search for Steam and install it.
   [image: Install Steam]

---

3. Make sure you untick 'Run Steam' before clicking finish.
   [image: Untick Run Steam]

---

4. Go back to PlayOnLinux click on the Steam icon and run it. Wait for it to finish updating.
   [image: Steam updating.]

---

5. You might get a message saying 'Steam crashed', click next and ignore it.
   [image: Steam crashed]

---

6. Log into Steam once has finished updating.
   [image: Steam login]

---

7. Steam will minimize once you are logged in. The 'Wine System Tray' will be open in a different window, find it and double click the Steam icon to open it.

[image: Wine system tray]

---

8. Find Age of Empires on Steam and install it.
   [image: 30 hours played]

---

9. Once it has installed run it from Steam, it will install some stuff and then immediately crash.
   [image: directx installing]

---

10. Go back to PlayOnLinux select 'Tools' on the toolbar at the top and Select 'Manage Wine Versions'. Wait a few seconds for the list to populate. On the x86 tab select '3.3' and click the arrow to move it to the right side.
    [image: installing wine 3.3]

---

11. Back on PlayonLinux, select Steam and select Configure.
    [image: configuring Steam]

---

12. Click onto the arrow next to 'Wine version' and select 3.3.
    [image: selecting wine version]

---

13. Still on the configure menu go to the tab 'Install components' and install 'd3dx9' and 'vcrun6'.

[image: d3dx9]
[image: vcrun6]

---

14. Go back to the 'General' tab and select 'Make a new shortcut from this virtual drive'. Find 'AoK HD.exe' and select Next.
    [image: adding a shortcut]

---

15. When it goes back to the shortcuts list, select 'I don't want to make another shortcut' and click next.

[image: finish adding a shortcut]

---

16.Download a copy of vcrun 2015 x86 from [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe). In the Miscellaneous tab of the configure menu select 'Run a Windows Executable (.exe) file in this virtual drive'.
[image: running an executable file]

---

17. Run your downloaded copy of VC redist 2015 and go through the setup.
    [image: install vcredist]
18. Run the AoK HD.exe shortcut we added earlier.
    [image: run the shortcut]

---

19. This error might appear, ignore it and click OK.
    [image: random error]

---

20. The launcher for Age of Empires will open, but there will be no text on the buttons, click the first button anyway and the game will launch :D
    [image: Launching the game]